# Passing hostname to Invoke-WebRequest to warm up web application

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I'm trying to generate requests to fire at our new versions of our .net web apps in IIS in order to start the app pools and warm them up.

The different versions are bound to local IPs and I'm trying to hit them with the following request as it looks like it will do the job:

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'http://172.28.36.31' -Headers @{host="www.mydomain.com"}
```

Now got the above working.

Any ideas on getting the same request to work over https and ignore and self signed cert warnings? There's a couple of options to ignore the warnings but haven't seen anything to use an ip with a custom host (akin to a local host entry)

Comment: If you are doing this interactivly, and you just want to see more information about the error, Powershell automatically keeps a list of all errors. To see the most recent one, inspect $error[0].

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a non-success http status code from the server which makes PowerShell throw an exception. Based on the "Object moved to here" message I assume it's going to be a redirect response.

You can check the status code by modifying your call like this:

```
try { 
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://172.28.36.31' -Headers @{host="www.mydomain.com"} 
} catch {
    $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__
}
```

Comment: The code sample is missing the '=' character. It should be _@{host='www.mydomain.com'}_.